# Compute mean and nmiss by group with multiple combinations in R, data.table

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, na

I'd like to compute the mean and count number of NA across several group combination with a large dataset. This is probably easiest to explain with some test data. I'm using the latest version of R on a Macbook Pro, and the data.table package (data is large, >1M rows). 
(note: I noticed after posting this that I accidentally used sum() instead of mean() for the "m = " variables below. I haven't edited it because I don't want to re-run everything, and don't think it matters that much)

```
set.seed(4)
YR = data.table(yr=1962:2015)
ID = data.table(id=10001:11000)
ID2 = data.table(id2 = 20001:20050)
DT <- YR[,as.list(ID), by = yr] # intentional cartesian join
DT <- DT[,as.list(ID2), by = .(yr, id)] # intentional cartesian join
rm("YR","ID","ID2")
# 2.7M obs, now add data
DT[,`:=` (ratio = rep(sample(10),each=27000)+rnorm(nrow(DT)))]
DT <- DT[round(ratio %% 5) == 0, ratio:=NA] # make some of the ratios NA
DT[,`:=` (keep = as.integer(rnorm(nrow(DT)) > 0.7)) ] # add in the indicator variable
# do it again
DT[,`:=` (ratio2 = rep(sample(10),each=27000)+rnorm(nrow(DT)))]
DT <- DT[round(ratio2 %% 4) == 0, ratio2:=NA] # make some of the ratios NA
DT[,`:=` (keep2 = as.integer(rnorm(nrow(DT)) > 0.7)) ] # add in the indicator variable
```

So, what I have is identifying info (yr, id, id2) and the data I want to summarize: keep1|2, ratio1|2. Specifically by yr-id, I want to compute the average ratio and ratio2 using keep and keep2 (thus compressing id2). I've thought of doing this either by subsetting by keep/keep2 the computing ratio and ratio2 or by matrix multiplication of keep*ratio, keep2*ratio, keep*ratio2 and keep2*ratio2.

First, the way I'm doing this that gets the right answer, but is slow:

```
system.time(test1 <- DT[,.SD[keep == 1,.(m = sum(ratio,na.rm = TRUE), 
                                nmiss = sum(is.na(ratio)) )
                      ],by=.(yr,id)])
   user  system elapsed 
 23.083   0.191  23.319
```

This works just as well in about the same time. I thought it might be faster to subset the main data first rather than within .SD:

```
system.time(test2 <- DT[keep == 1,.SD[,.(m = sum(ratio,na.rm = TRUE), 
                                nmiss = sum(is.na(ratio)) )
                       ],by=.(yr,id)])
   user  system elapsed 
 23.723   0.208  23.963
```

The problem with either of these approaches is that I need to do separate computations for each `keep` variable. Thus I tried this way:

```
system.time(test3 <- DT[,.SD[,.( m = sum(ratio*keep,na.rm = TRUE),
                                 nmiss = sum(is.na(ratio*keep)) )
                       ],by=.(yr,id)])
   user  system elapsed 
 25.997   0.191  26.217
```

This allows me to put all the formulas together (I could add in `ratio*keep2`, `ratio2*keep` and `ratio2*keep2`) but 1. it is slower and 2. it is not getting the correct number of NAs (see the `nmiss` column):

```
> summary(test1)
       yr             id              m               nmiss      
 Min.   :1962   Min.   :10001   Min.   : -2.154   Min.   :0.000  
 1st Qu.:1975   1st Qu.:10251   1st Qu.: 30.925   1st Qu.:0.000  
 Median :1988   Median :10500   Median : 53.828   Median :1.000  
 Mean   :1988   Mean   :10500   Mean   : 59.653   Mean   :1.207  
 3rd Qu.:2002   3rd Qu.:10750   3rd Qu.: 85.550   3rd Qu.:2.000  
 Max.   :2015   Max.   :11000   Max.   :211.552   Max.   :9.000  
> summary(test2)
       yr             id              m               nmiss      
 Min.   :1962   Min.   :10001   Min.   : -2.154   Min.   :0.000  
 1st Qu.:1975   1st Qu.:10251   1st Qu.: 30.925   1st Qu.:0.000  
 Median :1988   Median :10500   Median : 53.828   Median :1.000  
 Mean   :1988   Mean   :10500   Mean   : 59.653   Mean   :1.207  
 3rd Qu.:2002   3rd Qu.:10750   3rd Qu.: 85.550   3rd Qu.:2.000  
 Max.   :2015   Max.   :11000   Max.   :211.552   Max.   :9.000  
> summary(test3)
       yr             id              m               nmiss      
 Min.   :1962   Min.   :10001   Min.   : -2.154   Min.   : 0.00  
 1st Qu.:1975   1st Qu.:10251   1st Qu.: 30.925   1st Qu.: 2.00  
 Median :1988   Median :10500   Median : 53.828   Median : 4.00  
 Mean   :1988   Mean   :10500   Mean   : 59.653   Mean   : 4.99  
 3rd Qu.:2002   3rd Qu.:10750   3rd Qu.: 85.550   3rd Qu.: 8.00  
 Max.   :2015   Max.   :11000   Max.   :211.552   Max.   :20.00
```

What is the fastest way to get my 4 combinations of summarized info by yr-id?
Right now, I'm using option 1 or 2 repeated twice (once for keep, again for keep2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do summarization directly in expression in `j`:

```
# solution A: summarize in `.SD`:
system.time({
    test2 <- DT[keep == 1,
                .SD[, .(m = sum(ratio, na.rm = TRUE),
                        nmiss = sum(is.na(ratio)))],
                by = .(yr, id), verbose = T]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#  22.359   0.439  22.561

# solution B: summarize directly in j:
system.time({
    test2 <- DT[keep == 1, .(m = sum(ratio, na.rm = T),
                             nmiss = sum(is.na(ratio))),
                by = .(yr, id), verbose = T]
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.118   0.077   0.195
```

`verbose = T` is added to show the difference between the two approaches:

for solution A:

> lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as '.SD[, list(m = sum(ratio,
> na.rm = TRUE), nmiss = sum(is.na(ratio)))]' GForce is on, left j
> unchanged
>
> Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
>
> Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ...
> The result of j is
>
> > a named list. It's very inefficient to create the same names over and
> > over again for each group.
>
> When j=list(...), any names are detected,
> removed and put back after grouping has completed, for efficiency.
> Using j=transform(), for example, prevents that speedup (consider
> changing to :=). This message may be upgraded to warning in future.
>
> collecting discontiguous groups took 0.058s for 54000 groups
> eval(j) took 22.487s for 54000 calls
> 22.521 secs

For solution B:

> ...
>
> Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM)
> ... 0 sec lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(sum(ratio,
> na.rm = T), sum(is.na(ratio)))'
>
> GForce is on, left j unchanged
>
> Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged. Making each group and
> running j (GForce FALSE) ...    collecting discontiguous groups took
> 0.027s for 54000 groups   eval(j) took 0.079s for 54000 calls
> 0.168 secs

The main difference is that the summarization in B is treated as named list, which is extremely slow when there are many groups (54k groups for this data!). For a similar benchmark of this type see [this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36545111#36545111).

For the second part(your test3):
We didn't filter columns by `keep = 1` first. So those `NA`s where `keep !=`  is also counted in `nmiss`. Therefore, the count of `NA`s are different.

Comment: Brilliant. I'm still learning the details here, and didn't even know about the verbose option.

Comment: What about part 2: The second way (test3) doesn't work (I think) because ratios*keep gives NA even when keep = 0. Is there a way to do something like sum(is.na(ratios[keep])) to subset ratios first, then evaluate the is.na() function? I'd rather use this second approach because in the real data I have 7 versions of 'keep' and thus iterate this 7 times and then have to re-merge those 7 datasets. It would be much better to do it all in on step.

Comment: @JesseBlocher, see the edit about why the `NA` s are different. I have not came up a way to do this in one time better than for loops for multiple keep and ratio pairs.